# Python Pickle Loads Error

Tags: python, django, serialization, pickle

I have pickled a list of dictionaries using pickle.dumps. I save the string in a textfield in a MySQL database - being managed by Django. When I extract the string and try to unpickle the string to the list of dictionaries, I get the following error:

```
>>> pickle.loads(intlist1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1381, in loads
   file = StringIO(str)
TypeError: expected read buffer, ValuesQuerySet found
>>>
```

EDIT:
Figured out the work around. Could not understand the solution though.

```
pickle.loads(intlist1) #did not work
pickle.loads(intlist1[0].values()[0]) #works
```

I have no idea why that is the case though!

Comment: The error message clearly says that `intlist1` is of type `ValuesQuerySet`.  That's not a string.  Convert it to a string.

Comment: But I am getting intlist1 from a column in a table from the database where elements are stored as "Text" and I saved the element using pickle.dumps.

Comment: Nevertheless, you *are* passing an object of type `ValuesQuerySet` to `loads`, and that's why you're getting an error.  Your question is *really* about how to use your database correctly.  But you haven't said which database you're using, or shown any of the database storing or retrieving code.  Nobody can help you until you do.

Comment: By the way, are using Django?  If so, please say so.

Comment: Yes, I am. Sorry if that caused confusion

Comment: MySQL database. Column type as per model specification: interests = models.TextField(default=None,null=True)

Comment: OK, I added a "django" tag to your question.  I haven't used that, but I bet it's obvious to someone who has :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41879/discussion-between-pratik-poddar-and-tim-peters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a stupid mistake. Sorry.

I was getting intlist1 from the database as

.values('interests') and forgot to [0]['interests'][0] to get the value after that. Stupid mistake. Sorry. Thanks